# How to install MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: monodevelop

I'm not very experienced at Linux, so I simply want to know: how do I install MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 17.04?

I've tried the instructions on the MonoDevelop website, but I don't think it worked for me. Either that or I just was not able to follow instructions completely or accurately. I tried `sudo apt-get install monodevelop`, only to have a MonoDevelop with Run->Start Without Debugging and Start Debugging greyed out. Now I presume I will have to uninstall everything and try again? Linux is fun, but...oh Linux. ;)

Comment: What happens when you try to run a program from the terminal with *mono-complete* like in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905528/ubuntu-terminal-not-waiting-for-console-readkey-input/905732#905732 which also has instructions for running a C# program in a GUI application using MonoDevelop? Please post your error message if you get one. Flatpack didn't work so I'm trying to find another way to solve it.

Comment: I can run the program using mono <programname>. However, now I'm getting an odd message in MonoDevelop: File name invalid.

Comment: Sorry, now it works ok. However, I still have the greyed out Build and Run options.

Comment: Try it again next time you restart or boot to Ubuntu. I don't think it will work, so you don't need to waste a special reboot on this suggestion. logout/log back in without rebooting might also work. Also please make notes of everything you did, so that you can answer your own question if something works.

Comment: I'm not sure that will do anything, but I'll try it anyway. Thanks for the support. Also, you mentioned something like   "The easy way to get MonoDevelop to recognize mono-complete is to uninstall MonoDevelop and remove its config files using the command sudo apt-get purge monodevelop and then reinstall MonoDevelop." Should I try that as well?

Comment: Yes, that's worth trying and it would also be a good idea to start with code that has been tested in the terminal and works when it's run from the terminal.

Comment: So I've just uninstalled MonoDevelop using sudo apt-get purge monodevelop. Should I reinstall MonoDevelop using @Arun's suggestion, or simply with sudo apt-get install monodevelop? I don't really understand the difference. Are these two installations the same, or do they conflict and is that why my MonoDevelop doesn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61409/discussion-between-reincarnationofstackexchange-and-karel).

Answer (score 1):

First you should install `Flatpack` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Then install `MonoDevelop` with the following command:

```
flatpak install --user --from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref
```

To run `MonoDevelop` :

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
```

Comment: Build, run still greyed out. Help please!