# Any kind of browser activity is using all my CPU

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, 17.10, lenovo

I am using a brand new lenovo x1 carbon 5h generation and whenever i use a browser(chrome or firefox developer), all of my CPU cores suddenley run at more than 80%.

Just openning firefox causes my CPU to use a lot of resources. 
[image: htop output]
This is from running 4 tabs in firefox developer.

I have had this issue for a long time and was normally using chrome. On chrome the issue is even worse. There i have tried:

- reinnstalling chrome
- disable harware acceleration

I have tried some similar configurations on firefox as well as this approach: 
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/small-tweak-makes-firefox-linux-run-much-faster

Specs for mye machine:

[image: machine specs]

I basically only use my machine with:

- VS code
- a couple of terminal windows
- multiple browser windows with several tabs

My machine is also linked to a dock with two external monitors

UPDATE based on comments: 
Closing vs code seems to improve the performance a bit, and based onther issues it might be linked to some of the extensions i have installed:

- Azure account
- Azure app service tools
- Azure cli tools
- Azure resource manager tools
- Azure functions
- Azure cosmos db

But with all these extensions disabled, firefox is still using huge amount of resources:

[image]

Running atom instead is only having a slight improvement.

Comment: I don't think this link is a proper duplicate question because it's a corner case, but read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986779/c-on-ubuntu-terminal-or-visual-studio-which-is-the-better-option/986798#986798) anyway in case you accepted Visual Studio Code's prompts to install a lot of Windows software to go with it.

Comment: MonoDevelop IDE from the default Ubuntu repositories "would help" take the pressure off your maxed out CPU usage. MonoDevelop is lightweight and well-behaved compared to Visual Studio Code or Atom, however MonoDevelop cannot do all the good things that Visual Studio Code can do.

Comment: Not really sure I am willing to give up on VS code just yet. I will do some more research and hopefully find a solution.