# Package monodevelop-database is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: 18.04, mono, monodevelop

I was trying to install mono, but the command:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-database
```

is not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please note that monodevelop-database seems to be not inthe repositories after 16.04 - there is a launchpad ppa for up to 18.04, at [https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop/+packages](https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop/+packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDEs for running C# programs in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986779/)

Comment: **To reopen voters:** `monodevelop-database` does not appear in the Universe repository for Bionic: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=monodevelop-database&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all