# Cannot execute programs from MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop, c#

I clicked on "Run a console project" and it said that the program was built successfully.
But after that, I click "Run a console project" again and error like `Cannot execute /path/file.exe` appears as shown on the upper right corner of the screenshot. How can I fix this error?

[image: Screenshot for the error]

Answer (score 1):

After you have created  a new C# Console Project the way to build it in MonoDevelop is *Build* ->  *Build All*. A message at the top of MonoDevelop should appear that says: `Build successful.` The way to run it is to select *Run* -> *Run With* -> *Mono 4.x.x* (4.x.x stands for the Mono JIT compiler version).

A new terminal will open and show these results:

```
Hello Mono!

Press any key to continue...
```

If you run it again without closing the terminal, a popup window will open with the following message:

```
An application is already running. Do you want to stop it?
```

Click the *Stop* button to stop it and the C# program (Program.cs) will run again.

[image]

If your C# code ran successfully, you can find an executable file named Test3.exe in the `.../bin/Debug` folder of your console project. You can run Test3.exe from the terminal using this command:

```
mono /path/to/Test3.exe
```

Comment: i clicked to run with and it showed a window with 2 tab, general and advance. In the advance i can choose mono 5.2.0 or the default but nothing work

Comment: i just figure out that i uncheck run on external console in option run with, i can see the result just like netbean, inside the IDE. But some others cannot run. I want it can run normal  when i click 'run without debug" and it can run on terminal. It seem like it need some set up for this to run like i want?

Comment: mono 5.2.0 is not the same version of mono that is installed by the *mono-complete* package from the default Ubuntu repositories. For example, in my 16.04 the results of `apt policy mono-complete` are `mono-complete:  Installed: 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4` and the results of `apt policy monodevelop` are `monodevelop: Installed: 5.10.0.871-2` and my C# programs worked from the beginning out of the box with no additional setup or configuration required.

Comment: It appears from your comment that you have installed mono 5.2.0 Stable release (the latest version) from [the official Mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.2.0/) instead of the default Ubuntu mono-complete package. In case you are wondering about it, you don't need the latest versions of mono-complete or monodevelop to run .NET programs either: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905528/ubuntu-terminal-not-waiting-for-console-readkey-input/905732#905732

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I still got this problem in 2023 and got another solution.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39236556/6899155) post, Monodevelop expects specific terminals, with xterm being the ultimate fallback. Since Wayland comes without xterm, no console could be started (which was meant to start your program then).

I solved this by installing xterm on my system.